# Different solution of numpy.linalg.lstsq

Tags: numerical-linear-algebra, least-squares, python

Basically I have an overdetermined linear system of equations **Ax=b**, I can use *numpy.linalg.lstsq* to obtain the least square solution to this latter. However, when I multiply both sides of the equation by a weight diagonal matrix **F**, the least square solution is different while the equations are technically not. Here is a minimal example:

$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&2&3\\1&3&6\\1&6&2\\1&4&5\end{bmatrix}$
$b=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\\3\\4\end{bmatrix}$
$F=\begin{bmatrix}0.1&0&0&0\\0&1&0&0\\0&0&10&0\\0&0&0&2\end{bmatrix}$

The solution given of *numpy.linalg.lstsq* to **Ax=b** is
$x=\begin{bmatrix}-1.56643\\0.685315\\0.374126\end{bmatrix}$

The solution given of *numpy.linalg.lstsq* to **FAx=Fb** is
$x=\begin{bmatrix}-21.46375975\\3.27144095\\2.41928963\end{bmatrix}$

I though about the equations having different weights in the least square, leading to a different solution chosen by the algorithm, but I am not sure if this is the correct reasoning.

The code:

```
from numpy import array, diag, dot
from numpy.linalg import lstsq

A = array([[1, 2, 3], [1, 3, 6], [1, 6, 2], [1, 4, 5]])
b = array([1, 2, 3, 4]).T
F = diag([0.1, 1, 10, 2])
print(lstsq(A, b, rcond=None)[0]) #[-1.56643357  0.68531469  0.37412587]
print(lstsq(dot(F,A), dot(F,b), rcond=None)[0]) #[-21.46375975   3.27144095   2.41928963]
```

Comment: You really should add your code with questions like this. I was able to reproduce your example by writing the code myself, so I've edited your question. Edit: I get a different result for the second calculation; perhaps you can work out why.

Comment: I used **numpy.linalg.lstsq(numpy.dot(F,A), numpy.dot(F,b),rcond=None)**, maybe this makes a difference. Anyway our two results are different in both cases.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34142485/difference-between-numpy-dot-and-python-3-5-matrix-multiplication). You may want to edit your real code in now.